# iOS: Google SignIn not working if delegate is not UIApplicationDelete

Tags: ios, firebase, google-signin

I'm trying out Google SignIn to authenticate a user for my iOS app which uses Firebase.

After hacking the `GoogleSignInDependenies.framework` file to remove the duplicate classes, and adding the code as per the instructions on the Firebase and Google Sign In sites, I got it to work. Part of this was adding the `GIDSignInProtocol` protocol to the application delegate and implementing code inside the `func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!)` method.

I now want to set another class as the delegate of the sign in, but when I reassign the delegate, the callback never happens and I cannot for the life of me see why.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }

    public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        print("App delegate Signin")
    }
}

class FirebaseSecurity:NSObject, GIDSignInDelegate {

    override init() {

        super.init()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID

        // This works.
//        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! GIDSignInDelegate

        // This doesn't work
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        print("Security sign in")
        }
    }
}
```

Flicking the two lines back and forth in the security `init`, I can get the log to say:

```
App delegate Signin
```

When I tap the `GIDSignInButton` I added to my UI, but nothing when I switch to `FirebaseSecurity` as the delegate.

Anyone know why this is not working?

Comment: if you `print` something immediately after setting your delegate in your `FirebaseSecurity` object, does that line appear before or after you tap the `GIDSignInButton`?

Comment: Thanks Michael, found the problem and it was all me. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, my bad. Of course after taking the time to post this I almost immediately found the problem.

Which had nothing to do with Google Sign In.

I'd accidentally set  `FirebaseSecurity` as a transient instance in my I container so it was being dealloc'd before the logon button was pressed. Doh!

I'll leave the question here even though everything is working. Perhaps someone else will learn something from my mistake. :-)